# Greater flexibility on visibility of names/descriptions for groups on subscribe/unsubscribe pages

Tags: groups, smartgroups, mailing, unsubscribe, subscribe

I guess this is something of feature request cum support request. The naming of groups, and the descriptive text used for them has always been used primarily, in my usage at least over the last decade or so, to the benefit of the administrator/s, the people working with groups day to day for mailings, segmentation, etc.

I've always found it something of an irritation that I have to constrain my language in these fields simply because in certain circumstances, for example on subscribe/unsubscribe page for groups that are also mailing lists, this text is visible to end users. We're working around this to some extent by using CSS to hide the descriptive text on these user-facing pages, but this is something of a fudge. It would be so much easier to have admin-facing titles/descriptions that make sense for them, and at the same time present something much more suitable to end users.

Comment: This is also an issue for us when we use "send to search results" and use an unsubscribe group program-wide over different geographic lists that must be public, but isn't intended to be available as a subscription group, as some groups are. Since these are constantly changing I suppose we CAN hide them with CSS but we will have to continue to update that and it seems clunky.

Comment: Agree Graham, that would make sense.